Does the Flink Kubernetes Operator support Apache Flink Stateful Functions?
We have implemented Flink Stateful Functions. We are managing the Flink Job Lifecycle ourselves. Now, we want to migrate to Flink Kubernetes Operator but seems like kubernetes operator only supports: Stateless applications and Statful Applications built using DataStream APIs.
Flink Stateful Functions: https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-statefun-docs-stable/
Is there any reason for Flink Kubernetes Operator to not to support Flink Stateful Functions.?
